# What does the preposition "by" here stand for? Meaning of dowche

Tags: meaning, expressions, prepositions

I was reading a book and encountered a phrase in early modern English:

> "The Gothes speake
>   dowche, which I knowe by a dowcheman, my servunt, that was with
>   me there : for they understode one an other well enough, as we understande a furlane {i.e., a man of Forli) or a florentine."

I have asked this question because grammatically and, most importantly, logically it is very coherent with the modern English, despite being orthographicly dissimilar. But the usage of the preposition "by" here is ambiguos to me. What is the meaning of "to know something by someone" and dowche? Is dowche the name of a language? I couldn't find its definition.

Comment: Note that this is not Old English, nor even really old English. It’s (Early) Modern English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To know something **by** someone* here means that you know *something* because that *someone* has told/explained it to you. You got the knowledge of that *something* **through** that *someone*.

The speaker of that phrase got to know that 'the Gothes speake dowche' through his servant who is a dowcheman.

Comment: 'Dowche' is presumably 'Dutch'. In this context it probably means German (Deutsch) which used to be called 'High Dutch' by English speakers.